# Avoid conversion to scientific notation in awk

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I have a csv file that contains hundreds of columns.
I would like to subtract the value of a specific column from a static number and then print the entire line. 
The values of that column are long floats. 
When I do the subtraction awk automatically converts the result to scientific format.
I could use printf to get the standard representation but I need to get the entire row and the fields of each row are too many.

Is there a way to avoid this automatic conversion or at least to bypass it?

Answer (score 2):

From `man awk`:

A numeric expression is converted to string by replacing *expr* with *sprintf(CONVFMT, expr)*, unless *expr* can be represented on the host machine as an exact integer then it is converted to *sprintf("%d", expr)*. *Sprintf()*  is  an AWK built-in that duplicates the functionality of *sprintf(3)*, and *CONVFMT*  is a built-in variable used for internal conversion from number to string and initialized to "*%.6g*". 
Explicit type conversions can be forced, `expr ""` is *string* and `expr+0` is *numeric*.

So you can arrange *CONVFMT* variable on the beginning or format field.